# Using $rootScope to change background image of body in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using routes and would like to change my background image when I am on a specific route. For some reason the background image does not change/is not reading the value of my `rootScope`. I make the value true in my controller for the route that needs the different background image. Anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Can I not use `$rootScope` in my routes to change the class of my body?

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="ciscoImaDashboardApp" dynamicBodyBg ng-controller="navCtrl" >
```

JS:

```
.directive('dynamicBodyBg', function($rootScope, $route){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, el){
          $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',
            function() {
              if ($route.current.locals.needToChange()){
                el.css({background: url('images/background-bark@2x.jpg')});
              }
              else { 
                el.css({background: url('images/background@2x.jpg')});
              }
            }
          );
        }
    }

});
```

Routes:

```
angular.module('ciscoImaDashboardApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/welcome.html',
    controller: 'welcomeCtrl'
  })
  .when('/overall-results', {
    templateUrl: 'views/overall.html',
    controller: 'overallCtrl'
  })
  .when('/swim-lane-results', {
    templateUrl: 'views/swim-lane.html',
    controller: 'swimlaneCtrl'
  })
  .when('/key-exemplifiers', {
    templateUrl: 'views/key-exemplifiers.html',
    controller: 'petalCtrl'
  })
  .when('/key-exemplifiers/:exemplifier', {
    templateUrl: 'views/single-exemplifier.html',
    controller: 'keyCtrl',
    resolve: {
      needToChange: function(){
        return true; //or false
      }
    }
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });

});
```

Comment: Are you using angular ui-router ?? to make myself clear , do want to display different images for different ui-router state in view ??

Comment: @SameerK yes I have different routes in my view and would like to change the background color of the body element that all my views share depending on which route I am on. I updated my question and am now showing my route file.

Comment: Supposed to be `navCtrl` in this one?
`angular.module('ciscoImaDashboardApp').controller('keyCtrl', function ($scope,    
$rootScope) {
    $rootScope.exemplifierPage = true;
});`

Comment: P.S Suggest you to switch to ui-router, which is much easier to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ng-route, you can do the following:

Add this directive to your `body` element.

```js
app.directive('dynamicBodyBg', function($rootScope, $route){
  return {
    link: function($scope, el){
      $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',
        function() {
//your router has changed and u can change the background
//add the logic here
          if ($route.current.locals.needToChange){
            el.css({background: url('//whatever background u want'});
          }
          else { 
            el.css({background: url('//restore'});
          }
        }
      );
    }
  }
});
```

In your `$routeProvider`

```js
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/welcome.html',
    controller: 'welcomeCtrl',
    resolve: {
      needToChange: function(){
        return true; //or false
      }
    }
  })
```

P.S Suggest you to switch to ui-router, which is much easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: What is current.locals supposed to do? 

Making the body a directive doesn't change the background image. Nothing in the directive function is recognized. Refer to my updated question.

Comment: directive name should be "dynamic-body-bg"

Comment: I'm getting this error:
$route.current.locals.needToChange is not a function

Comment: yes sorry, it is a typo, should be just
`$route.current.locals.needToChange`
was writing the code from top of my head :)

Comment: isn't that what I did?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by creating a rootScope and changing it for all the views.

```
$rootScope.backgroundImg = "url('../images/background@2x.jpg')";
```

And then using it in my view like this:

```
<body ng-app="ciscoImaDashboardApp" ng-controller="navCtrl" ng-style="
{'background-image': backgroundImg}" >
```